# Populate field values on Page load using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js

I am trying to populate few fields in html on page load.

I tried using ng init and $watch to set the values in the fields but both results in undefined error.

Please help

HTML code:

```
    <div ng-init="loadModifyValues()">
    <table  id="modifyTable" >
    <tr>
        <td >
            <span> Name</span> 
        <td >
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="modify.name" ></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Controller JS:

```
$scope.loadModifyValues= function(){
    $scope.modify.name = 'John';
}
```

TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

Tried $watch and window.onload as well but same error:

```
$scope.loadModifyValues= function(){
        //$scope.modify.name = 'John';
    }

$scope.$watch("modify.name", function(){
        //console.log($scope.testInput);
        $scope.modify.name = 'John';
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining `modify` before assigning the name value to it.

```
$scope.loadModifyValues= function(){
    $scope.modify={};//need to define this variable first
    $scope.modify.name = 'John';
}
```